# how to install ccny_g2o

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody
I need to install ccny_rgbd_tools stack but I am getting errors, and none of the suggested solutions helped. Therefore I decided to install ccny_g2o package first. I have cloned the the source file but I dont know how to install/rosmake it. I have tried both commands:

```
    rosmake ccny_g2o
    rosmake socrob-ros-pkg
```

and I get error.

I'm using ROS fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04
I get errors when running "rosdep install" and also when running "rosmake"

when I rosmake the latest version of ccny_rgbd_tools from  https://github.com/ccny-ros-pkg/ccny_rgbd_tools.git, I get the following result:
In the last part of the result, it is mention that "Halting due to failure in package lib_rgbdtools."

**result for rosmake latest ccny-rgbd-tools**

```
user@user-U30Sd:~$ rosdep install ccny_rgbd_tools
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
ccny_rgbd: Missing resource genmsg
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/user/fuerte_workspace/sandbox
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [3]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [4]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

user@user-U30Sd:~$ rosmake ccny_rgbd_tools
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ccny_rgbd_tools']                         
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141203-195153
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ccny_rgbd_tools'] to:
['ccny_rgbd', 'ccny_openni_launch', 'ccny_rgbd_data', 'lib_rgbdtools']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ccny_rgbd_data [ make ]                                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ccny_rgbd_data ROS_NOBUILD in package ccny_rgbd_data
 No Makefile in package ccny_rgbd_data
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2                 
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospack  No Makefile in package rospack                
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> opencv_tests [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< opencv_tests ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv_tests       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice          
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                 
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                  
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> flann [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< flann ROS_NOBUILD in package flann                     
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> image_geometry [ make ]                                
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package image_geometry   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> test_nodelet [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport 
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl           
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                             
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< test_nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package test_nodelet       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> polled_camera [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< polled_camera ROS_NOBUILD in package polled_camera     
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> ccny_openni_launch [ make ]                            
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration_parsers
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< ccny_openni_launch ROS_NOBUILD in package ccny_openni_launch
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs              
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_srvs  No Makefile in package std_srvs              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> lib_rgbdtools [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> camera_info_manager [ make ]                           
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< camera_info_manager ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_info_manager
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
 No Makefile in package kdl
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< visualization_msgs  No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> mk [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< mk  No Makefile in package mk                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> eigen_conversions [ make ]                             
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf_conversions [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< eigen_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen_conversions
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package tf_conversions   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> cv_markers [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< cv_markers ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_markers           
[ rosmake ] Last 40 linesb_rgbdtools: 22.2 sec ]     [ 1 Active 49/51 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  -- Could NOT find openni (missing:  OPENNI_INCLUDE_DIRS) 
  ** WARNING ** visualization features related to openni will be disabled
  -- looking for PCL_COMMON
  -- Found PCL_COMMON: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_common.so 
  -- looking for PCL_KDTREE
  -- Found PCL_KDTREE: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so 
  -- looking for PCL_OCTREE
  -- Found PCL_OCTREE: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_octree.so 
  -- looking for PCL_SEARCH
  -- Found PCL_SEARCH: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_search.so 
  -- looking for PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS
  -- Found PCL_SAMPLE_CONSENSUS: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so 
  -- looking for PCL_FILTERS
  -- Found PCL_FILTERS: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_filters.so 
  -- looking for PCL_TRACKING
  -- Found PCL_TRACKING: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_tracking.so 
  -- looking for PCL_SURFACE
  -- Found PCL_SURFACE: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_surface.so 
  -- looking for PCL_IO
  -- Found PCL_IO: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_io.so 
  -- looking for PCL_SEGMENTATION
  -- Found PCL_SEGMENTATION: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so 
  -- looking for PCL_VISUALIZATION
  -- Found PCL_VISUALIZATION: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_visualization.so 
  -- looking for PCL_FEATURES
  -- Found PCL_FEATURES: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_features.so 
  -- looking for PCL_REGISTRATION
  -- Found PCL_REGISTRATION: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_registration.so 
  -- looking for PCL_KEYPOINTS
  -- Found PCL_KEYPOINTS: /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so 
  -- Found PCL: /usr/lib/libboost_system-mt.so;/usr/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.so;/usr/lib/libboost_thread-mt.so;pthread;/usr/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.so;/usr/lib/libboost_iostreams-mt.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_common.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_common.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libflann_cpp_s.a;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libflann_cpp_s-gd.a;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_kdtree.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_octree.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_octree.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_search.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_search.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_sample_consensus.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_filters.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_filters.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_tracking.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_tracking.so;optimized;/usr/lib/libqhull.so;debug;/usr/lib/libqhull.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_surface.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_surface.so;vtkCommon;vtkRendering;vtkHybrid;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_io.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_io.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_segmentation.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_visualization.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_visualization.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_features.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_features.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_registration.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_registration.so;optimized;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so;debug;/opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_keypoints.so 
  -- Searching for g2o ...
  CMake Error at cmake-modules/FindG2O.cmake:93 (message):
    Could not find libg2o!
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:37 (find_package)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package lib_rgbdtools written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141203-195153/lib_rgbdtools/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< lib_rgbdtools [FAIL] [ 22.22 seconds ]                 
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package lib_rgbdtools. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 50 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141203-195153
```

and when I rasmake the older version, I get this:
In the last part of the result, it is mention that "Halting due to failure in package ccny_g2o." That's why I thought of installing ccny_g2o package.

**result for rosmake older ccny-rgbd-tools**

```
user@user-U30Sd:~/fuerte_workspace/sandbox$ rosmake ccny_rgbd_tools
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['ccny_rgbd_tools']                         
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141203-153912
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['ccny_rgbd_tools'] to:
['ccny_g2o', 'ccny_rgbd', 'ccny_openni_launch']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild              
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospack [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospack  No Makefile in package rospack                
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib
 No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy                    
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice          
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs              
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs    
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2                 
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> ccny_g2o [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest                
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge             
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> opencv_tests [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< opencv_tests ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv_tests       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag                  
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]                                
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf                  
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> flann [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< flann ROS_NOBUILD in package flann                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                 
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration_parsers
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> image_geometry [ make ]                                
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport 
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> polled_camera [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< polled_camera ROS_NOBUILD in package polled_camera     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< image_geometry ROS_NOBUILD in package image_geometry   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> test_nodelet [ make ]                                  
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> ccny_openni_launch [ make ]                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl           
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< test_nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package test_nodelet       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]                             
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< ccny_openni_launch ROS_NOBUILD in package ccny_openni_launch
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs              
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl
 No Makefile in package pcl
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> visualization_msgs [ make ]                            
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
 No Makefile in package kdl
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< std_srvs  No Makefile in package std_srvs              
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> camera_info_manager [ make ]                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> eigen_conversions [ make ]                             
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< visualization_msgs  No Makefile in package visualization_msgs
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< eigen_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen_conversions
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf_conversions [ make ]                                
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> mk [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< camera_info_manager ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_info_manager
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< mk  No Makefile in package mk                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf_conversions ROS_NOBUILD in package tf_conversions   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cv_markers [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cv_markers ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_markers           
[ rosmake ] All 3 linesccny_g2o: 127.4 sec ]         [ 1 Active 49/51 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  svn --no-auth-cache --trust-server-cert --non-interactive co -r 30 https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o/trunk g2o-svn
  svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o/trunk': could not connect to server (https://svn.openslam.org)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package ccny_g2o written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141203-153912/ccny_g2o/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< ccny_g2o [FAIL] [ 127.45 seconds ]                     
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ccny_g2o. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 50 packages with 1 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/user/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141203-153912
```

Sorry that my question is too long.Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198738/how-to-install-ccny_g2o/) by [anonymous21007](https://answers.ros.org/users/21007/anonymous21007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2014-12-02**:
What version of ROS are you using? Also, we need to know exactly what errors you are getting. Please edit your question to provide both of these pieces of information.

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2014-12-03**:
+1 to @jarvisschultz I want to add that you also should read the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials). This will answer a lot of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is openni installed?

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0